# Wildcard and mutator methods

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard

I was totally confused, when saw this snippet:

```
class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<? super Animal> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Dog());  //it's OK
        list.add(new Animal()); //and this is OK too
    }
}
```

Why such things are allowed? When i changed my list to `List<? super Dog> list = new ArrayList<>();`compile-time error occurs in `list.add(new Animal());` With `extends` wildcard all combinations cause errors. Who can tell the exact reason of this behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for Generics PECS.

Comment: Think of it this way: a dog is an animal, but an animal is not a dog.

Comment: i know PECS, how it applies here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    List<? super Animal> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Dog());  //it's OK
    list.add(new Animal()); //and this is OK too
```

The above code is allowed as it should be :
because A dog is also an animal.

```
    List<? super Dog> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Dog());  //it's OK
    list.add(new Animal()); //error
```

The above code is an error as it should be again,
because not every animal is a dog.

`inheritance` is as simple as this. :)

NOTE: To complete the answer I refer to this super good answer in :

[[Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java]])[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java])

Comment: Of course! Thanks. But what about `extends`? Why we cannot put `Dog` in `List<? extends Dog>`?

Comment: @Jskyi I think this is what you are asking abt mate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java]